# UIView does not update new height constraint after action

Tags: swift, xcode, uiview, autolayout, uiviewanimation

I have an issue of updating the UIView's height after an action (or in other words, when a button is tapped).
So basically I have created a UIView class called "BottleView" where there is another view that animates a "wave animation" inside the bottle.

When the percentage goes up, the height of the Animation View increases and updates. When the percentage goes down, the height decreases and updates.

Whenever it decreases, it updates the Animation View's height immediately. But when increasing the height, it does not immediately update. In order to see the updated height constraint, I have to relaunch the app.

Am I missing a step? Here is a gif for visual purposes and my code below

[image: Bottle GIF]

```
class BottleView: UIView {

    let liquidView = AnimationView()
    let shapeView = UIImageView()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setup()
    }

    func setup() {
        self.backgroundColor = .blue

        self.shapeView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        self.shapeView.image = UIImage(named: "water-bottle")

        self.addSubview(liquidView)
        self.mask = shapeView

        liquidView.anchor(top: .none, leading: leadingAnchor, bottom: bottomAnchor, trailing: trailingAnchor)

        layoutIfNeeded()

        playWavesAnimation()
        animationObserver()
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        shapeView.frame = self.bounds

        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name("refreshWaveForBottle"), object: nil)
    }
}

extension BottleView {

    fileprivate func animationObserver() {
         NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(refreshWaterAnimation), name: NSNotification.Name("refreshWaveForBottle"), object: nil)
     }

    @objc func refreshWaterAnimation() {
        NetworkManager.fetchPercentageAmount { (value) in

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if value > 0 && value <= 5 {
                    self.liquidView.constrainHeight(constant: 50)
                    self.liquidView.layoutIfNeeded()
                }

                if value > 5 && value <= 10 {
                    self.liquidView.constrainHeight(constant: 80)
                    self.liquidView.layoutIfNeeded()

                }

                if value > 10 && value <= 15 {
                    self.liquidView.constrainHeight(constant: 100)
                    self.liquidView.layoutIfNeeded()

                }

                if value > 15 && value <= 20 {
                    self.liquidView.constrainHeight(constant: 150)
                    self.liquidView.layoutIfNeeded()

                }

                if value > 20 && value <= 25 {
                    self.liquidView.constrainHeight(constant: 200)
                    self.liquidView.layoutIfNeeded()

                }

                if value > 25 && value <= 30 {
                    self.liquidView.constrainHeight(constant: 250)
                    self.liquidView.layoutIfNeeded()

                }

                if value > 30 && value <= 35 {
                    self.liquidView.constrainHeight(constant: 300)
                    self.liquidView.layoutIfNeeded()

                }

                if value > 35 && value <= 40 {
                    self.liquidView.constrainHeight(constant: 350)
                    self.liquidView.layoutIfNeeded()

                }

                if value > 40 && value <= 45 {
                    self.liquidView.constrainHeight(constant: 400)
                    self.liquidView.layoutIfNeeded()

                }

                if value > 45 && value <= 50 {
                    self.liquidView.constrainHeight(constant: 500)
                    self.liquidView.layoutIfNeeded()

                }

                if value > 50 && value <= 55 {
                    self.liquidView.constrainHeight(constant: 600)
                    self.liquidView.layoutIfNeeded()

                }

                if value > 55 && value <= 60 {
                    self.liquidView.constrainHeight(constant: 700)
                    self.liquidView.layoutIfNeeded()

                }

                if value > 60 && value <= 65 {
                    self.liquidView.constrainHeight(constant: 800)
                    self.liquidView.layoutIfNeeded()

                }

                if value > 65 && value <= 70 {
                    self.liquidView.constrainHeight(constant: 900)
                    self.liquidView.layoutIfNeeded()

                }

                if value > 70 && value <= 75 {
                    self.liquidView.constrainHeight(constant: 1000)
                    self.liquidView.layoutIfNeeded()

                }

                if value > 75 && value <= 80 {
                    self.liquidView.constrainHeight(constant: 1100)
                    self.liquidView.layoutIfNeeded()

                }

                if value > 80 && value <= 85 {
                    self.liquidView.constrainHeight(constant: 1200)
                    self.liquidView.layoutIfNeeded()

                }

                if value > 85 && value <= 90 {
                    self.liquidView.constrainHeight(constant: 1300)
                    self.liquidView.layoutIfNeeded()

                }

                if value > 90 && value <= 95 {
                    self.liquidView.constrainHeight(constant: 1400)
                    self.liquidView.layoutIfNeeded()

                }

                if value > 95 && value <= 98 {
                    self.liquidView.constrainHeight(constant: 1450)
                    self.liquidView.layoutIfNeeded()

                }

                if value > 98 {
                    self.liquidView.constrainHeight(constant: 1800)
                    self.liquidView.layoutIfNeeded()

                }

                if value < 1 {
                    self.liquidView.frame.origin.y = self.bounds.height
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

extension BottleView {

    fileprivate func playWavesAnimation() {
        let waveAnimation = Animation.named(waveJSONFile)
        liquidView.animation = waveAnimation
        liquidView.clipsToBounds = true
        liquidView.animationSpeed = 2.0
        liquidView.respectAnimationFrameRate = false
        liquidView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        liquidView.loopMode = .loop
        liquidView.backgroundBehavior = .pauseAndRestore
        liquidView.play()
      }
}
```

In case you guys are wondering what "Constrain Height" does... this is a helper method for auto layout.

```
extension UIView {
    func constrainHeight(constant: CGFloat) {
        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: constant).isActive = true
    }
}
```

Comment: share code of  `constrainHeight`

Comment: Hey there Sh_Khan, I just updated my question with the code for constrainHeight()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove old 1

```
extension UIView {
    func constrainHeight(constant: CGFloat) {
        constraints.forEach {
           if $0.firstAttribute == .height {
                self.removeConstraint($0)
           }
        } 

        heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: constant).isActive = true
        superView!.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```